# How to get lng lat value from query results of geoalchemy2

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, postgis, geoalchemy2

For exammple,

```
class Lake(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'lake'
     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     name = Column(String)
     geom = Column(Geometry('POLYGON'))
     point = Column(Geometry('Point'))


lake = Lake(name='Orta', geom='POLYGON((3 0,6 0,6 3,3 3,3 0))', point="POINT(2 9)")
query = session.query(Lake).filter(Lake.geom.ST_Contains('POINT(4 1)'))
for lake in query:
     print lake.point
```

it returned `<WKBElement at 0x2720ed0; '010100000000000000000000400000000000002240'>`

I also  tried to do **lake.point.ST_X()** but it didn't give the expected latitude neither

What is the correct way to transform the value from WKBElement to readable and useful format, say (lng, lat)?

Thanks

Comment: not an answer, but `ST_X()` is for longitude—not latitude, which is from `ST_Y()`

Answer (score 14):

You can parse WKB ([well-known binary](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcsde/9.1/general_topics/wkb_representation.htm)) points, and even other geometry shapes, using **shapely**.

```
from shapely import wkb
for lake in query:
    point = wkb.loads(bytes(lake.point.data))
    print point.x, point.y
```

Answer (score 5):

http://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.org/en/0.2.4/spatial_functions.html#geoalchemy2.functions.ST_AsText is what you are looking for. This will return 'POINT (lng, lat)'.  ST_X ought to work, though, so you may have another issue if it isn't returning the correct value.

Comment: Do you mean lake.point.ST_AsText()? It returned <geoalchemy2.functions.ST_AsText at 0x2bfc050; ST_AsText>
, but not a value. thanks

Comment: Just tried, it returned the same thing. I found session.scalar(lake.point.ST_AsText()) will return the expect result, however, it asked DB for the conversion, is it the expected behaviour?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by it asked DB for the conversion?

Comment: ST_AsText is a Postgis function, so if that is what you mean by your question, then, yes, it is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Extending John's answer, you can use `ST_AsText()` while querying like this -

```py
import sqlalchemy as db
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
from geoalchemy2.functions import ST_AsText

# connection, table, and stuff here...

query = db.select(
    [
        mytable.columns.id,
        mytable.columns.name,
        ST_AsText(mytable.columns.geolocation),
    ]
)
```

Find more details on using functions here - https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/0.2.6/spatial_functions.html#module-geoalchemy2.functions

Answer (score 0):

Using shapely.

```
from shapely import wkb
for lake in query:
    point = wkb.loads(lake.point.data.tobytes())

    latitude = point.y
    longitude = point.x
```

Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/30203761/5806017

Answer (score 0):

I did it the following way

```
class BusDepotGeoFence(models.Base):
    __tablename__ = "bus_geofence_data"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    area = Column(Geometry("POLYGON"))
```

The querying part as follows

```
    query = select(ST_AsGeoJSON(BusDepotGeoFence.area).label("area"))
    results = await db.execute(query)
    results = results.fetchall()
    results = [i[0] for i in results]
    results = [json.loads(result) for result in results]
```